# CName of website

Tags: wordpress, dns, cname

My website doesn't work without www. It is not working since I installed WordPress.

Pardon me, I am not trying to market my site. But here it goes

`http://www.stratageeks.com` works

`http://stratageeks.com` doesn't

My settings in wordpress

[image]

If I remove `www` from both those places than the situation is other way, I have problem with `www`

Do I need to digg some place else? CName or what?

Comment: Do you have a server admin / hosting provider you can talk to? This sounds like a job for them

Comment: I have the access, I am doing all the roles for my company :) You can tell me

Comment: This certainly sounds like a DNS or domain forwarding issue rather than a WordPress issue.  You could try resaving your permalinks, but I don't think that will probably do anything to resolve this. Just put "website doesn't load without www" into the Google Machine and you'll get all kinds of info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your DNS settings. You can check in with your hosting provider and make sure that the A Name for stratageeks.com, and that the CNAME www. points to stratageeks.com. The A Name usually contains the IP to your server and CNAME points to a web address